React Native Hermes-engine Sandbox error in Xcode: rsync.samba deny file-write-create during build
When I try to run the app on the iOS simulator (iPhone 15, iOS 17.5), I encounter a sandbox error related to rsync.samba. The specific error messages are:
Sandbox: rsync.samba(18075) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/vrtechsol/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DermPro-brtigadkswuknhfeyqfvrkuganwx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/hermes-engine/Pre-built/hermes.framework/.Info.plist.wddhxQ
and
Sandbox: rsync.samba(18075) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/vrtechsol/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DermPro-brtigadkswuknhfeyqfvrkuganwx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/hermes-engine/Pre-built/hermes.framework/.hermes.HeTRbR
he project was previously running smoothly on a real device, but switching to the simulator caused this issue. I’ve tried cleaning the build and restarting Xcode, but the error persists.
This is my podfile :
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  # use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'DermPro' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'DermProTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      # :ccache_enabled => true
    )
  end
end

To resolve this issue, I’ve tried :

Deleting node_modules, the Pods folder, and the Podfile.lock file, then reinstalling dependencies.

Cleaning the build folder in Xcode and deleting the DerivedData folder.

Following a Stack Overflow suggestion to change ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING to NO in Xcode build settings.


but still getting the issue
